# Call stored procedure in java with query from 2 database

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, database-connection

I have 2 databases (DatabaseA, DatabaseB) on the same server host.

I write stored procedure using data from both databases and it is working fine. But when I am using java code to connect and call the stored procedures it is giving following excepton:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line
>   1

I think reason is my java code connect string. I open only 1 databaseA => databaseB in query is NULL, right?
I think the reason for this error is that i am able to connect only one database that is database A.While database B query is returning null?
what are your suggestions???

Comment: i think you should have two connection pools for both DBs and use those connections from pool. If you are already doing it then good and share code. Otherwise do not use single pool to connect to both dbs as it will keep switching for db connections which is not good practice.

Comment: we can't help if you show nothing